# Script to change the SQL Default database location in windows

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2005, sqlcmd, defaultlocation

Can someone help me with any script like windows script, BAT script or SQLcmd script for changing the default database location of SQL.

I am using Windows

Comment: Why are you using such an out dated, and unsupported, version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will fit to SQL Server 2005 as I use 2017 Express on my laptop,
but give it a try...

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', REG_SZ, N'C:\DATA'
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', REG_SZ, N'C:\DATA'
GO
```